# Code equivalent for following Rally Query

Tags: rally

Wondering what would be the rally-node or RallyRestToolkitFor.NET code equivalent for the following query. Rally portal returns 200+ but when implementing this code in rally-node and RallyRestToolkitFor.NET I get far less results. Thanks

```
(((((((((((((ClosedDate >= 2016-12-22)) OR (State != Closed))  AND 
(FunctionalArea != Documentation)) AND  (FunctionalArea != Testing)) AND
(FunctionalArea != Performance)) AND  (FunctionalArea != "QW")) AND
(FunctionalArea != "QLR"))  AND (FunctionalArea != "TSD")) AND (FunctionalArea != 
"TUL")) AND  (FunctionalArea != "D")) AND (Tags.Name != "NCI")) AND (CreationDate 
<= 2016-12-21))

restApi.query({
    type: 'defect',
    limit: Infinity, //the maximum number of results to return- enables auto paging
    fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'ScheduleState', 'PlanEstimate', 'Iteration', "Tasks", "Release", 'CreationDate', 'ClosedDate', "Project", "Owner"], 
    query: query,
}, function(error, result) {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        //console.log(result.Results);
        //console.log(js2xmlparser.parse("Defects", result.Results));
        var file = 'rally.json'
        jsonfile.writeFileSync(file, result.Results)
    }
});
```

or

```
Request request = new Request("Defect");
string queryString = "big_blob_of_query";
request.Query = new Query(queryString);
request.Fetch = new List<string>() { "Name", "Description", "FormattedID", "CreationDate", "ClosedDate", "Project"};

QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(request);
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is project scoping.  It doesn't look like you're supplying any project scoping information, so the query is probably just defaulting to your default project scope (probably not what you want).

If you set a project + scope up/down do you get the results you'd expect?

```
restApi.query({
    scope: {
        project: '/project/12345',
        down: true
    }
});
```

or

```
request.setProject("/project/12345");
request.setProjectScopeDown(true);
```

Comment: Thanks again Kyle!
Since I am not specifying any projects, it means this node module somehow defaults to an arbitrary project?
Also how can I make it so that it is dynamic and I do not have to provide a literal project number /project/12345.
I want all defects for all projects

Comment: The default project logic is implemented in wsapi, and so is shared by all toolkits.  If you want all projects you can just set workspace: /workspace/12345 in the scope object without a project.

Comment: Nice, looking better every time when using workspaces. But it still seems that I am missing something, not all of the defects are coming in. Does the request.Project = "Buju" work? Maybe I need to get workspace --> Projects --> Defects. Thanks for helping

Comment: hmm, that all should work fine... does your workspace have one top level project?  you could go back to setting project to that and project scope down true.  i'm not sure exactly what's going on...